# Generic method return dynamic for unknown reason

Tags: c#

I have the following generic method signature

```
public static T? TryConvertToEnum<T>(object obj, T? defaultValue = null) where T : struct, IConvertible
```

which is working fine! The problem I have is there seems to be a unexpected behaviour from VS in this call:

```
dynamic dynamicValue = "1";
var value= ConversionHelper.TryConvertToEnum<MyEnum>(dynamicValue);
```

the problem is that the Type of "value" is "dynamic" and I don't know why I'd expect it to be "MyEnum?"

Did anyone expected this behavior or know why this is happening?

Comment: With C# 7.3 you can use `where T : Enum`

Comment: @SebastianHofmann For which you need VS 2017.7....

Comment: `dynamic` is a type...it is not syntactic sugar like `var`.

Comment: You can declare your variable as MyEnum value instead of var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost *everything* you do with a value of type `dynamic` results in a value of `dynamic`. Sure, you know the return type of the `TryConvertToEnum` method you intend to call - but you're passing in a dynamic argument, which means it's not bound until execution time. At execution time, there could be a whole other method with a `string` parameter and a different return type.

There are a *very* few cases of expressions which include dynamic values but still don't have a result type of `dynamic`. Off the top of my head, they are:

- Constructor calls (always the type being constructed)
- The `is` operator (always bool)
- The `as` operator (always the type named as the second operand)

In your case, just use `object` instead of `dynamic` and the call will be statically bound instead, and `value` will be of type `MyEnum?`.

Comment: ...Which is a good reason to avoid `dynamic` whenever you can.